# Is this method of writing jQuery append technically correct?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm converting from Prototype JS to jQuery and changing statements from:

```
inputElement = divElement.appendChild(new Element("input", {"type": "text"}).addClassName('xs_input'));
```

to:

```
divElement.append(inputElement = $("<input/>", {"type": "text"}).addClass('xs_input'));
```

I realise I could write it on separate lines, eg.

```
inputElement = $("<input/>", {"type": "text"}).addClass('xs_input');
divElement.append(inputElement);
```

But is there anything wrong, or any downside, with doing it in one statement? It appears to work, at least in Chrome.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a code review, which belongs on [codereview.se]

Comment: javascript may allow you to assign to a variable while passing arguments to a method, but that's against common logic and would be a bad practice for readability and code consistency

Comment: Seems fine, using two lines and a `var` statement is probably easier on the eyes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery Way™ tends to be to chain everything as much as possible to keep the code in a readable state. If I had to write that code, I'd take advantage of the [`appendTo` method](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/):

```
$("<input/>", {"type": "text"})
    .addClass('xs_input')
    .appendTo(divElement);
```

Additionally, there's no need for the `addClass` call just to set the `[class]` attribute:

```
$('<input>', {
    'type': 'text',
    'class': 'xs_input'
}).appendTo(divElement);
```

Comment: Thanks, I need to assign the newly created element to a variable, so using appendTo has solved it so I can do it in one line. Sorry for being off topic, this was my first post and didn't realise, I'll use Code Review for questions like this in future.